# Is there a way to have (animated)GIF image as system tray icon with pyqt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, system-tray

I have created static(PNG) image as tray icon with pyqt.

Did the same with GIF image results in static tray icon. Can it animated in system tray with pyqt?

```
QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, parent)
self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("Image.gif"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `QMovie` to play the animated gif, and update the tray icon on each new frame event:

```
m_icon = new QSystemTrayIcon();
m_icon->show();
m_gif = new QMovie(":/animated.gif");
connect(m_gif, SIGNAL(frameChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updateIcon()));
m_gif->start();
```

...

```
void MyWidget::updateIcon()
{
    m_icon->setIcon(m_gif->currentPixmap());
}
```

Sorry for the C++ example, I don't have PyQt installed.