# How can I have an animated system tray icon in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, system-tray

I am trying to create an animated systray icon for a pyqt4 app but am having trouble finding any examples in python. This is the closest I can find but it's in C++ and I don't know how to translate it over: [Is there a way to have (animated)GIF image as system tray icon with pyqt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816445/is-there-a-way-to-have-animatedgif-image-as-system-tray-icon-with-pyqt)

How can I go about doing this either with an animated GIF or by using a series of still images as frames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Create `QMovie` instance to be used by `AnimatedSystemTrayIcon`. Connect to the `frameChanged` signal of the movie and call `setIcon` on the `QSystemTrayIcon`. You need to convert the pixmap returned by `QMovie.currentPixmap` to a `QIcon` to pass to `setIcon`.

Disclaimer, only tested on Linux.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class AnimatedSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def UpdateIcon(self):
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(self.iconMovie.currentPixmap())
        self.setIcon(icon)

    def __init__(self, movie, parent=None):
        super(AnimatedSystemTrayIcon, self).__init__(parent)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Exit")
        self.setContextMenu(menu)

        self.iconMovie = movie
        self.iconMovie.start()

        self.iconMovie.frameChanged.connect(self.UpdateIcon)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    trayIcon = AnimatedSystemTrayIcon(movie=QtGui.QMovie("cat.gif"), parent=w)

    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Anim Systray')
    w.show()

    trayIcon.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. its worked for me. +1 to question and +1 to answer.